# Pandas Selecting column by number for analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I realize that you can select data by column number by using `iloc` (eg `inf1.iloc[:,3]`) returns the third column. However, when I try to use this to use a column to filter rows, it doesn't work. For example, if the column title is *Summary* then `inf2 = inf1[inf1.Summary == 'GREEN']` creates a dataset with all of the rows that have *GREEN* in the Summary column, 
but `inf2 = inf1[inf1.iloc[:,3] == 'GREEN']` doesn't. Any help is much appreciated. I suspect I've missed something obvious.

To be clearer, I import a large csv file.

```
Station ID, Unnamed:1, Summary, Fault, Unnamed: 4 etc etc
558656,     New Lane,  GREEN,   NO,    11000
558656,     New Lane,  AMBER,   NO,    11000
558656,     New Lane,  RED,     NO,    11000
558656,     New Lane,  GREEN,   NO,    11000
```

And wish to return only the lines with *GREEN* in the summary column, before running some further analysis.

- Attempt: `inf2 = inf1[inf1.Summary == 'GREEN']` created what I wanted but
  relied on column names, which can change between versions of this
  file despite the data columns staying in the same order.
- Attempt: `inf2 = inf1[inf1.iloc[:,3] == 'GREEN']` didn't work,
- Solution: the suggested `inf2 = inf1[inf1[inf1.columns[2]] == 'GREEN']`
  did, which has solved my issue, thanks to @quapka in the comments.

Comment: What about `inf2 = inf1[inf1[inf1.columns[2]] == 'GREEN']`?

Comment: @quapka that does work! thank you. I obviously needed the extra inf1, though I don't quite understand why! Thanks very much.

Comment: `inf1.columns[2]` gets the name of the third column in `inf1`. The `inf1[inf1.columns[2]]` uses the name of the third column to get it from `inf1` and then it can be compared to with `== 'GREEN'` this creates mask of `True/False` (this might not be precise), which is then used to get the correct rows from `inf1`.

Comment: What is it returning? The two methods of selecting the summary column to be green are equivalent. Please rewrite your question with a reproducible example. There's no way to tell what's going on otherwise.

Comment: Why are you using `inf1.iloc[:,*3*]` if it's column *2*? pandas column indexing starts at 0... maybe try `inf1.iloc[:, 2]` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should work; there must be something else going on. Here's a reproducible example that works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df[df.iloc[:,3]>40]
```

Comment: I have realised the issue, in the first line of my answer "inf1.iloc[:,3] returns the third column". It returns the 4th column. Spent so long trying to get the data in order I missed a simple column misnumbering. Thank you for your help! Incidentally when trying to run your example code the df = pd.DataFrame line gives me "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 100), indices imply (4, 100)"

Comment: Ahh yes, I had a lot of those errors myself when first moving from R to zero-indexing. Glad you figured it out, and thanks for pointing out the typo in my example. It's corrected.